# How to remove blank space in AlertDialog?

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to show an AlertDialog that prompts the user for picking a color. I did it, however, there is a lot of blank space between the ColorPicker and the action buttons:

[image]

How can I remove the blank space and make the dialog only as big as it should be? I have tried using a `Dialog` instead of an `AlertDialog`, and also wrapping my content inside a `Column` with `mainAxisSize` set to `MainAxisSize.min`, but neither worked. One curious thing is that the value passed to `contentPadding` seems to cause no effect on the UI. I have tried different values and it keeps the same.

This is the code:

```
void _showColorPickerDialog() {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
            title: Text('Pick a color'),
            content: MaterialColorPicker(),
            actions: [
              FlatButton(
                  child: Text('CANCEL', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
                  onPressed: Navigator.of(context).pop),
              FlatButton(
                  child: Text('OK', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
                  onPressed: Navigator.of(context).pop),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
```

The (Material ColorPicker) package's author provides some code showing how to do this, which is quite similar to mine, but it has the same problem. Maybe my Flutter version is not the same as his. Anyways, do you guys know any good approach to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe it can works; Give height to MaterialColorPicker function

`content: Container(height:250, child: MaterialColorPicker(),)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for you:
`content: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [MaterialColorPicker()]),`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap MaterialColorPicker in **Column** and give mainAxisSize to **MainAxisSize.min**

```
void _showColorPickerDialog() {
showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(6.0),
        title: Text('Pick a color'),
        content: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, 
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [MaterialColorPicker()]),
            actions: [
              FlatButton(
                  child: Text('CANCEL', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
                  onPressed: Navigator.of(context).pop),
              FlatButton(
                  child: Text('OK', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
                  onPressed: Navigator.of(context).pop),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Set `scrollable` property to `true`.